# Should tags about previous solutions be removed from a question

Tags: discussion, tags

I was reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37587405/python-extract-url-from-url-file) question, because I was browsing the [batch-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-file) tag. However, upon reading it, the only text relevant to batch-files was:

> and I am currently using a batch file to get the job done

The question itself however, is not about batch-files in any way. Should this tag be removed?

Comment: _"Should this tag be removed?"_ Yes.

Comment: ^I just removed it, the tags should relate directly to the question being asked. What the op is currently doing isn't really relevant in this situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the '[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)' section in the help center, it states:

> **Include all relevant tags**
>
> Try to include a tag for the language, library, and specific API your
>   question **relates to**.

I've added my own emphasis on the 'relates to' part, but I think the heading says it all when it states 'relevant tags'. If it's clear that a tag isn't relevant to the question then remove it. As you found, this will mislead users into looking at a question that they believed to be on a topic they could help with, but ultimately they may end up wasting their time reading.